# Is MongoDB built for a lot of updates?

Tags: mongodb, performance, indexing, database

I'm creating a blog.

Everytime someone views the page of a blog, can I do this:

```
post['views'] += 1
db.collection.save(post)
```

I don't index 'views'.

Comment: 1. Indexing views would not help this scenario anyway (since you're not querying based solely on its value)

2. Your question title could use a rename: something like "Best way to increment counters in MongoDB". The answer to your current title ("Is MongoDB built for a lot of updates?") is no (for certain values of "a lot").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [$inc](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24inc) (or your driver's implementation), it does an atomic update.

You should be good, but as with anything it will depend on your traffic volume.

Comment: What if I already selected the mongo document? All I have to do is +=1 and .save.  Do I still have to use $inc?  Wouldn't using $inc do a query twice?

Comment: $inc is going to do the action entirely within the server.  You wouldn't pull the document, just send it the $inc command with the document query.  If you look at your driver page / docs it should have an example.

Comment: The `$inc` is the cleanest way to do this and saves on traffic. Unless your framework is really smart, the .save() may try to save the whole object. Personal suggestion time. I would do two increments: `views.total` and `views.20110105`. So that's one for totals and one for each day. It will take up more space, but it will allow you to track history on the views (and it's a very inexpensive operation).

Comment: $inc is also the only operation that ensures your value is accurate re. concurrency: what if 2 clients access the very same post at the very same moment? A and B retreive the post (with the same "views" value), A and B increment the "views" value, then A and B save the post; in the end while the post was seen twice, the counter as only be incremented once. You wouldn't have those kind of issues with $inc.